# 'Too many re-renders' when checking for length of input

Tags: reactjs

I have a form and trying to validate the username that name should be more than 5 characters long, but after when I am checking it is giving too many re-renders.

```
const UserName = (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState('');
  if (props.val.length < 5) {
    setError('Username is short');
  }
  return (
    <div className='m-2 d-flex flex-column'>
      <label htmlFor='username'>Username</label>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        id='userName'
        onChange={props.userInput}
        value={props.val}
        placeholder='enter your name'
      />
      <span className='error' style={{ color: 'orangered' }}>
        {error}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

onChange and value is coming from the parent component.

How do I check for input length?

Answer (score 2):

Run this code inside an `useEffect` like so:-

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (props.val.length < 5) {
    setError('Username is short');
  }
},[props.val])
```

The above `useEffect` only runs when `props.val` changes.

You're currently running this code inside the main function body so each state update will re-trigger a render and again your logic.